# Is it possible to expose a Swift function with default parameters to objective-C as multiple methods?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've got a Swift function that has a default parameter.

```
class Derp: NSObject{
    @objc(derp:derpsalot:)
    func derp(derpington: Int, derpsalot: Double = 0.0){

    }
}
```

Is there any way to have this imported into Objective-C as two methods? I'd like to be able to call the function in Objective-C with or without the default parameter.

```
[myDerp derp:123];
[myDerp derp:123 derpsalot:456.789];
```

Is this possible? or do I have to write two separate functions in Swift?

Comment: The answer is **No** till date.

Comment: @nayem Thanks, it does look like a duplicate.